# Do we need to configure any specific settings in OBIEE to access BI Publisher via SOAP or REST API's?

Tags: rest, soap, soapui, obiee, bi-publisher

We are trying to access **BI Publisher** reports that are created in our **OBIEE** (Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition) via **SOAP** or **REST** API's.

When we try to access a report directly via browser UI (https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:443/xmlpserver) we are able to view (or attain) the results.

However, we were not able to achieve it via either of the API's (SOAP or REST).

We are suspecting any **configuration** (or settings) needed on the OBIEE end, but unable to figure out the root cause that is blocking (frequently returning random errors) the **API calls**.

Please advise on the settings needed.